# Given two list of strings, how can I convert them into a into a dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, list-comprehension

I have the following list of strings:

```
content = [['a list with a lot of strings and chars 1'], ['a list with a lot of strings and chars 2'], ['a list with a lot of strings and chars 3'], ['a list with a lot of strings and chars 4']]

labels = ['label_1','label_2','label_3','label_4']
```

How can I create a dictionary from them:

```
{
'label_1': ['a list with a lot of strings and chars 1']
'label_2': ['a list with a lot of strings and chars 2']
'label_3': ['a list with a lot of strings and chars 3']
'label_4': ['a list with a lot of strings and chars 4']
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dictionary = dict(zip(labels, content))
```

### Various versions:

```
def f1(labels, content):
    return dict(zip(labels, content))

def f2(labels, content):
    d = {}

    for i, label in enumerate(labels):
        d[label] = content[i]
    return d

def f3(labels, content):
    d = {}
    for l, c in zip(labels, content):
        d[l] = c
    return d

def f4(labels, content):
    return {l : c for (l, c) in zip(labels, content)}

def f5(labels, content):
    dictionary = {}

    for i in range(len(content)):
       dictionary[labels[i]] = content[i]
    return dictionary

def f6(labels, content):
    return {l : content[i] for (i, l) in enumerate(labels)}
```

### Timing

These are tested using **Python 3.6.7**. Note that different versions of Python might have different performance, so you should probably re-run the benchmarks on your intended platform.

```
In [20]: %timeit f1(labels, content)
637 ns ± 4.17 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [21]: %timeit f2(labels, content)
474 ns ± 4.44 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [22]: %timeit f3(labels, content)
447 ns ± 2.76 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [23]: %timeit f4(labels, content)
517 ns ± 4.44 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [24]: %timeit f5(labels, content)
529 ns ± 8.04 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit f6(labels, content)
602 ns ± 0.64 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

### Fastest

Fastest is `f3`, a modification of the answer by @Michael_MacAskill to use `zip` instead of using the index to extract the value from `content`.

Interestingly, a dictionary comprehension of @Michael_MacAskill 's answer did not perform better than the one using plain for-loops. Perhaps the implementers of the language realized that people still stuck with for-loops most of the time and implemented some performance hack for them.

### Most Pythonic

Most experienced Python programmers will probably go with the `dict(zip(labels, content))` option if the differences in speed is not critical since it is a common idiom in the language.

Answer (score 2):

```py
dictionary = {}                                                         

for i in range(len(content)): 
   dictionary[labels[i]] = content[i] #setting each element in labels list as key and each corresponding index of content list's content as value
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could be done more efficiently with a dictionary comprehension but here is a quick and dirty way:

```
d = {}                                                                                                                

for i, label in enumerate(labels): 
    d[label] = content[i]
```

Comment: and actually the answer by @lightalchemist is far more elegant.

Comment: which answer is the most efficient?

Comment: That depends on your metric of efficiency, but if it is simply "lines of code typed", I would certainly go with @lightalchemist as the accepted answer.